# Error bar in Mendix

Tags: mendix

My error bar list in Mendix seems missing because I clicked the wrong thing (which I had no clue). How do I fix this since I need to find the errors before my program starts working?

Answer (score 6):

You can reset your screen layout via *Menu bar > View > Reset Layout* or add views such as Error list view  via [Menu bar > View > Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWBBK.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image: View the error list by select View >> Error List]

You can open it again by go to menu bar to select View tab then select Error List. The final one is Reset Layout, it will give you a new default layout.

You also can post your question to Mendix Forum

https://forum.mendixcloud.com/